# How to use scons to build cpp files: each file with an executable?

Tags: c++, executable, program-entry-point, scons

I've a cpp file directory having files like:

```
a.cpp b.cpp c.cpp xy.cpp ....
```

Each cpp file has a main function, so I wish to build each file into an executable. So how do I use scons to find and loop all these source files and build them each? Note that env.Glob(xxx) will build all files into one, not as I expected.

Would you kindly help to suggest?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
env=Environment()
for f in env.Glob("*.cpp"):
  env.Program("${SOURCE.base}",f)
```

This should make a bunch of programs named a,b,... from source files a.cpp, b.cpp...

Comment: more info regarding the `${SOURCE}` and `${TARGET}` variables and the other suffixes like `.base` can be found here: https://scons.org/doc/HTML/scons-man.html#variable_substitution